# Jquery Ajax Does Not Send Accept Header

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

Here's my ajax call:

```
function fetchAccount(email, callback) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://example.com/",
    jsonp: "callback",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    headers: {"Accept" : "application/javascript; charset=utf-8"},
    success: function(data) {
      appState.user = data;
      appState.viewState = AppStates.CONTENT_VIEW;
      AppStore.persistToLocalStorage();
      callback();     
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
      appState.user = "";
      appState.viewState = AppStates.LOGIN_FAIL_VIEW;
      AppStore.persistToLocalStorage();
      callback();
    }    
  });
};
```

My server isnt returning JSONP because the accept header isn't actually set properly. When I use the "modify headers" google chrome extension to manually inject "Accept" "application/javascript; charset=utf-8" the server responds with JSONP just fine.

I captured the request header and as expected, "Accept" isnt being set properly:

```
GET /api/accounts/myemail@gmail.com?callback=jQuery22009572079558856785_1454040030107&_=1454040030108 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.97 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,et;q=0.6
```

What's going on here - how can I get it to properly set the accept header? It seems so simple...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that i'm expecting the wrong thing. According this this jquery bug report (https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7694) when you do JSONP you're not actually firing an XHR so you can't control the headers.

Answer (score 0):

When you request `JSONP` you are asking for a script to be sent back that executes the callback you are giving it. The proper Accepts header for a script would be `application/javascript` not `application\json`. Seems to me that your server is the one in the wrong here, not jQuery.  That said, you could try setting the `accepts` property in the AJAX settings to `application/json` and see if that works.  I do not think that should be necessary nor would I recommend it even if it works; I would suggest you fix the server if possible.

From the [jQuery,ajax API docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> If jsonp is specified, $.ajax() will automatically append a query string parameter of (by default) callback=? to the URL. The jsonp and jsonpCallback properties of the settings passed to $.ajax() can be used to specify, respectively, the name of the query string parameter and the name of the JSONP callback function. The server should return valid JavaScript that passes the JSON response into the callback function. $.ajax() will execute the returned JavaScript, calling the JSONP callback function, before passing the JSON object contained in the response to the $.ajax() success handler.

Comment: Oops, i was trying to fix this and copied a bad example from the interwebs. Here's the right content type and it still fails... See above

Comment: @Patrick Are you sure you need JSONP, not JSON. If you're making the request to a server in the same domain as the web page, you should be using plain JSON. JSONP is an older way of getting around cross-origin policies. A better way, today, would be to use CORS if that is supported. If the server is in the same domain, though, you wouldn't need to do either.

Comment: The server is fine here - i was asking for application/json and getting it. After correcting it to application/javascript i still get the same result.

Comment: Yes, I definitely need jsonp...Even so, this wont be the last request header I need to set - soon i'll need to pass credentials via headers and i'd like to set those as well...

Comment: Still, according to the request, the browser will accept anything. The server should send the response. What response code are you getting from the server?

Comment: The request is wrong - I accept only application/javascript. If I forcibly set the header to have Accept: application/javascript using a chrome plugin it works great. ... Also, i dont understand the format of the jquery **accepts** section... do you know?

Comment: It's an object so something like `accepts: { 'jsonp': 'application/javascript' }`

Comment: This is the answer. I'm expecting the impossible - no xhr is being issued so i cant influence the header as it's set by the browser. https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7694

Comment: Yeah, that makes perfect sense since you're requesting a script.

Comment: It's frustrating tho - i really just want to use JSONP so i can have a single REST endpoint that returns either json or jsonp, and I can do quick front end dev on my local while hitting my remote backend server. Now i'm going to have to deploy to the same domain just to test.

Comment: What about using CORS and supporting cross-origin requests?

Comment: I haven't read up on cors much. For now I'm using a chrome browser plugin to force the cors header and allow easy dev. I think that's actually the easiest way to achieve my goal..